# Equations For Spiral Where The Difference Between the size of 'Arcs' Decreases By A Constant

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, curves, parametric

**'Loops' / "Arcs" refers to PI RAD / 180 deg**

Sorry for the long title. I was playing around with hyperbolic Spirals today, and noted, as you all know, that the difference between the size of their 'arcs' / 'loops' decreases towards the center, i.e., the 'arc' / 'loops' get more similar as the graph gets closer to 0 (see fig). This happens 'hyperbolic-ally.' So, I naturally wondered if it's possible to do the same thing via a constant, for instance,

$$0.4^{0}*(Difference)$$
$$0.4^{1}*(Difference)$$
$$0.4^{2}*(Difference)$$
$$0.4^{3}*(Difference)$$
$$0.4^{4}*(Difference)$$

And so on.

This seems possible, but I can't quite get it and would be thankful for help!

[image]

Comment: Agreed, log spirals aren't log spirals lol! As far as what I want, think of it this way:

$$(1/t)*sin(t*PI)$$
$$t$$

The waves in this sine wave (which is the same as my spiral from the side) get more similar as you go to 0.

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: @YvesDaoust To be more specific, size is, by definition how close an arc is to 0, in this case. The closer you are to 0, the smaller the arc will have to be.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, that's not the answer. A so-called log spiral decreases / increases by a constant. I want something where Not the size, but the difference in size, or ratio between loops decreases by a constant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I didn't I answered it in two different ways, see above! Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes, I know the way I used the term wasn't totally (really) by the book.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm thinking about deleting this and then trying to figure out why you're not understanding it and then riposting a better version.

Comment: If you do understand, would you mind writing parametric equations for it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know plenty about log spirals, what I'm referring to is NOT a log spiral.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, $$exp(t*ln(PHI)/PI))*sin(t),$$
                         $$exp(t*ln(PHI)/PI))*cos(t)$$

I know this well and it's not what I'm referring to at all.

Comment: Have a good year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the difference in radii between consecutive arcs of the spiral were to increase by a constant amount with each 180 degree turn, then the radius would be increasing at a rate of some constant *k>0* per $\pi$ radians. This relationship can be written in polar coordinates as *r*=$\frac{k\theta}{\pi}$. Using the the transformation from polar to Cartesian coordinates: $(r,\theta)\rightarrow(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta))$, we can parameterize the spiral as $s(\theta)=(\frac{k\theta}{\pi}cos(\theta),\frac{k\theta}{\pi}sin(\theta))$.